# I don't know when to use reverse() in django.core.urlresolvers module

Tags: django, django-urls

I finished reading the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) for the `reverse()` method of the Django URL dispatcher.

When is it useful?

Thank you!

Comment: Usecase:
A user submits a form. The form is processed; an object is created and added to your database. You want to respond by returning a detailed view of the created object. This can be done with `return reverse(myDetailView, kwargs={'pk':self.object.pk})` for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function supports the [dry principle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry) - ensuring that you don't hard code urls throughout your app. A url should be defined in one place, and only one place - your [url conf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/). After that you're really just referencing that info.

Use `reverse()` to give you the url of a page, given either the path to the view, or the `page_name` parameter from your url conf. You would use it in cases where it doesn't make sense to do it in the template with `{% url 'my-page' %}`.

There are lots of possible places you might use this functionality. One place I've found I use it is when redirecting users in a view (often after the successful [processing of a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#processing-the-data-from-a-form))-

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('thanks-we-got-your-form-page'))
```

You might also use it when writing template tags.

Another time I used `reverse()` was with model inheritance. I had a `ListView` on a parent model, but wanted to get from any one of those parent objects to the `DetailView` of it's associated child object. I attached a `get__child_url()` function to the parent which identified the existence of a child and returned the url of it's `DetailView` using `reverse()`.

Answer (score 3):

The reverse() function is used in django to achieve  DRY compliant urls in your views.
Find a clearer explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241668/what-is-reverse-in-django%22%20%3E)

Comment: It's best to quote the explanation from that site and then cite them as a source, so that even if the site goes down your answer is fully available on SO.

Answer (score 2):

It's used when you want to resolve a view by name along with arguments to a URL in code. It's the backend for the [`{% url %}` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Comment: Can you explain a little more?

Comment: There's really nothing else to explain. You will know when, if ever, you need it.