# Using URL in Django Views? Possible?

Tags: python, django

I have `content` = 'Please get me the Python book you talked about, @friend'

Then this in my **views.py**:

`new_content = re.sub(r'(@\w+)', r"<a href='#'>\g<0></a>>", content)`

This returns

```
new_content = 'Please get me the Python book you talked about, <a href='#'>@friend</a>'
```

I want if a user clicks of `@friend`, it should redirect to this **url**:

```
url(r'^user/(?P<user_name>\w+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
```

How do I include this url(`profile`) in `<a href='#'></a>` in my **views.py** as I would have done in Django template like this `<a href="{% url 'mysite:profile' user.username %}">@{{user.username}}</a>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use reverse()

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url_name'))
```

You can check this [answer for reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241668/what-is-reverse-in-django)
And the [documentation for the function.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)

You may need to pass arguments. You can do it like this:

```
reverse('profile', kwargs={'user_name': 'auth'})
```

For your case you can try:

```
content = 'Please get me the Python book you talked about, @friend'
new_content = re.sub(r'(@\w+)', r"<a href='%s'>\g<0></a>>" % (reverse('profile', kwargs={'user_name': 'friend_username'})), content)
```

Comment: You mean something like `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))`?

Comment: This is not working. It says `NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) t
ried: []`

Comment: It may be cuz you are trying to resolve an url that takes 1 argument and you are not sending it. Check my edit.

Comment: Let me know if this works or need something else to figure out

Comment: This did it. Thank you. But it is not rendering the HTML <a> tag in my page. I have asked another question on it. If you could help. I'd be grateful.

Comment: Sorry, all links are directed to one user. The one passed as parameter. How do I make it all dynamic to the mentions found in a post?

Comment: You need to get the specific username, but that depends on your project . If you need for example the user that made the request you can get it with something like: request.user.username

Comment: That's the one I am doing currently as a click on any link takes you to currently logged in user instead of mentioned user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63425/discussion-between-cdvv7788-and-yax).

Answer (score 0):

You already named argument it's `user_name`

```
# urls.py
url(r'^user/(?P<user_name>\w+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),

# views.py
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    """
    Takes keyword argument 'user_name'
    and looks for it in database:
    User.objects.get(username='dude')
    """
    model = User
    slug_field = 'username'
    context_object_name = 'user'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'user_name'
    template_name = 'user_detail.html'

# Pass your keyword argument
<a href="{% url 'mysite:profile' user_name=user.username %}">@{{ user.username }}</a>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer to my question?

Comment: "I want if a user clicks of @friend, it should redirect to this url:"
You need correct url tag, slug_field and slug_urlkwarg defined in views. So yes, it is.