# Django render is not refreshing page after a form submission

Tags: django, django-templates, render

After almost a full day trying to make things work, I resign... I need some help because I don't understand where I'm doing things the wrong way.
I searched SO and stumbled on many answers about redirection and so on...

Let me give you some context :
I have a simple form where one can upload a file, so far, it's working well. I want the user to be redirected to another page after the upload is successful and this is where it fails :'(

My views.py :

```
# Create your views here.
def thank_you(request):
    data = {'text': 'Thank you for your file'}
    print('thank you blablabla')
    print(data)
    return render(request, 'app/thank_you.html', data)


def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
            new_file = UploadFile(file=uploaded_file)
            new_file.save()
            return redirect(reverse(thank_you))
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()

    data = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'app/drop_file.html', data)
```

I do see the 2 prints in the 'thank_you' function, meaning that the redirect is working as expected. But the view doesn't refresh and I'm stuck.
And if I try to access the url directly (going to http://.../thank_you/ ) it does show correctly.

The thank_you.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Upload done</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello !</h1>
<h1>{{ text }} </h1>

</body>
</html>
```

The form looks like that :

```
    <form id="my-dropzone" class="dropzone" action="{% url 'home' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
    <button id="submit-all">
        Submit all files
    </button>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
            // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
            autoProcessQueue : false,

            init : function() {
                var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
                myDropzone = this;

                submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    myDropzone.processQueue();
                    // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
                });

                // You might want to show the submit button only when
                // files are dropped here:
                this.on("addedfile", function() {
                    // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
                });

                this.on("queuecomplete", function() {
                    console.log('should we redirect ?');
                });

            }
        };
    </script>
```

And my urls.py file :

```
url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
url(r'thank_you/$', views.thank_you, name='thank_you'),
```

Nothing out of the ordinary I guess.

Even if I change the 'home' to :

```
    if form.is_valid():
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
        new_file = UploadFile(file=uploaded_file)
        new_file.save()
        data = {'text': 'Thank you for your file'}
        print('thank you blablabla')
        print(data)
        return render(request, 'app/thank_you.html', data)
```

The view doesn't update, I do see the prints in the django console but the template does not render...

I would like the `return render(request, 'app/thank_you.html', data)` to actually refresh the page after the form is submitted but I can't achieve to do so :( Any help ?

Firebug show me this in the console :
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epBNM.png)

Comment: what exactly is the thank you page supposed to show?

Comment: Actually, just a <h1> tag with the text, it's working well when called directly but it's not showing when called just after the form upload.

Comment: can you add that template to the question

Comment: To me it doesn't look like you're using [reverse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11241936/3579910) properly.

Comment: Well spotted @TemporalWolf at the point at which reverse is called thank_you isn't defined. so it seems the OP hasn't shared his real code with us.

Comment: But I do see the two prints embedded in the function, should I do something else ? I tried using quotes or switching to HttpResponseRedirect but it ends with the same behavior.
@e4c5 : it is my real code :) I changed nothing in it

Comment: @e4c5 you misunderstand: Reverse is used on a URL or view object, he's giving it `render()` which returns an `HttpResponse`. I am no Django expert, but I question whether that is valid.

Comment: You can see my latest edit : even changing the 'home' function does not behave like I would want

Comment: @TemporalWolf yes, I did misunderstand. But my statement that thank_you is undefined at this point is also valid return `redirect(reverse(thank_you))`

Comment: You're submitting your form through js, so it is normal that you are not redirected, you can use js for redirection like `window.location.href = "thank_you/"`

Comment: Thank you @ettanany, and what if I wanted to do it through Django ? How should I make it ? (form submission and redirect)

Comment: @K.Tran-Cong  You will need to use the default form submission by adding submit button inside the form tag