# Receiving a NoReverseMatch error while trying to add the username to the url after login

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

When a user clicks 'login' I want them to be logged in and redirected to i.e., **www.exampledomain.com/accounts/usernameGoesHere/**

Here are my top level urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

# Namespace URLs
app_name = "pto_request"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
]
```

and here are the urls for accounts:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from accounts.views import (login_view, register_view, logout_view)
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    # root url will look like www.website.com/accounts/

    url(r'^login/$', login_view, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout_view, name='logout'),
    url(r'^register/$', register_view, name='register'),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[0-9a-zA-Z._]+)/$', login_required(views.IndexView.as_view()), name = 'index'),
]
```

This is my login view:

```
def login_view(request):
    title = "Login"
    user_form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if user_form.is_valid():
        username = user_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = user_form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect(reverse('accounts:index', args=[username]))
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'user_form':user_form, 'title':title})
```

and finally this is the traceback log of the error I am receiving:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/accounts/FlashBanistan/

Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'datetimewidget',
 'accounts']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\django projects\PTO\accounts\templates\accounts\index.html, error at line 0
   Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/(?P<username>[0-9a-zA-Z._]+)/$']   1 : {% extends 'base.html' %}
   2 : {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
   3 : 
   4 : {% block content %}
   5 : 
   6 : {{ form.media }}
   7 : 
   8 : 
   9 : <div class="container">
   10 :   <div id="calendar">


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  109.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  86.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  315.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  439.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "C:\Users\achesley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  392.             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /accounts/FlashBanistan/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/(?P<username>[0-9a-zA-Z._]+)/$']
```

Comment: Can you not 'redirect()' them from the login_view?

Comment: why can't you just 'return redirect("accounts/%s" % username)' from the login_view?

Comment: your code doesn't look safe, btw; at the point when you do login(), the user may be None.

Comment: Safe as in stable or safe as in secure? I can't just return what you put because my url isn't setup to accept a string.

Comment: Why even append the username.  Can't you get that from `request.user` on the subsequent account view?

Comment: It looks better aesthetically for the URL to reflect something about the user logged in vs logged out. I do have access to request.user in all of my views, my question was about appending the username to the URL. I'm going to try a few of these answer tomorrow and let you all know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. Move your `index` url to the last, and give it a pattern to accept username only. Moving `index` url to the last is important, or it will override all the others url in the same urls file, e.g., `login`, `logout`.

```
app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^login/', login_view, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', logout_view, name='logout'),
    url(r'^register/', register_view, name='register'),
    #
    # +------------ this url should come at last !!!!
    # |
    # v
    url(r'^(?P<username>[0-9a-zA-Z._]+)/$', login_required(views.IndexView.as_view()), name = 'index'), name = 'index'),
)
```

Step 2. `redirect` to your `index` url with the logined user name.

```
return redirect(reverse('accounts:index', args=(username, )))
```

**EDIT 2 Fixing template error**

According to your stack trace, the error occurred in your template, and django can't reverse a url for `index`. After checking your code in your template, I found that, you have called a `url` function with `accounts:index` as parameter, but without specifying the username kwarg in your method call.

So you can fix the error with the code below:

```
{% if user %}
<li><a href="{% url 'accounts:index' user.username %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{ user.username }}</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Wow i don't know how long it would have taken me to find this bug. I'll look into it more in the morning but was there anything in the error stack that would have pointed me in this direction? I would like to learn how to parse the errors better.

Comment: i am focusing on the stack trace...  it say Template error... so it must be some where in your template using a wrong url.. so finally i got this defect...

Comment: if you want to edit your posted answer to reflect what you figured out I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Django's url accept pattern, that means, you can setup a url for home page like:

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[a-zA-Z]*)$', views.userhome, name = 'index'),
```

In your user's index view, you will get a variable from url, so the function(same for Class-based-view) will like:

```
def userhome(request, username):
```

To use this url, you can use `reverse` function:

```
#after login...
return redirect(revers('index', args=[username]))
```

And here are some useful tips for you:

1. Better write your decorator in your views.py, since writing in your urls.py will make it too messy.
2. Try to user [reverse function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241668/what-is-reverse-in-django) to get a url instead of writing in your code directly

For further information about reverse and url config, you may refer to [Django's doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to add the username in as a querystring in your redirect function. This way you don't have to change your urls:

```
return redirect("/accounts/?username=%s" % user.username)
```

Additionally, you can get the user from `request.user` in the view (without having to add it to the url), which is what I'd recommend -- other than if for aesthetic purposes you want it in the url.

Here's another login function for reference that fixes some of the issues discussed in the comments of your question:

```
def login(request):

    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    if username and password:

        # Make sure its an active user, or else return an error message.
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            auth_login(request, user)
            next = request.session.get('next', 'root')
            return redirect(next)
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "Invalid username / password.")

    return render(request, 'login.html')
```