# NoReverseMatch at /force-password-change/ when changing password

Tags: python, django

I am using django user system,

There comes the error like this when user trying to change the password, It looks like some url routing is wrong.

```
NoReverseMatch at /force-password-change/
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost.example.jp:8010/force-password-change/
Django Version: 3.2.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: /Users/whitebear/.local/share/virtualenvs/example-admin-mg9y4sUV/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  /Users/whitebear/.local/share/virtualenvs/example-admin-mg9y4sUV/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.10
Python Path:    
['/Users/whitebear/MyCode/httproot/suntory_cdk/example-admin',
 '/Users/whitebear/MyCode/httproot/suntory_cdk/example-admin/example-shared-models',
 '/Users/whitebear/MyCode/httproot/suntory_cdk/example-admin/$PYTHONPATH',
 '/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.9.10/lib/python39.zip',
 '/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.9.10/lib/python3.9',
 '/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.9.10/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/whitebear/.local/share/virtualenvs/example-admin-mg9y4sUV/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

This error happens arround here,

in `users/views.py`

```
class PasswordChangeView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "users/password_change.html"
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("")

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.request.user.username)
        return render(request, self.template_name,
                      {"form": form, "email": user.email})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("password is posted")
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            user = get_object_or_404(User, username=request.user.username)
            user.set_password(data["new_password1"])
            user.is_require_pwd_change = False
            user.save()
            return super(PasswordChangeView, self).form_valid(form)

        return super(PasswordChangeView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is reverse()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241668/what-is-reverse)

Comment: The problem is `success_url = reverse_lazy("")`. `reverse_lazy` like `reverse` expects the first argument to either be a view or a url name.

Comment: It solves the problem I set `reverse_lazy("myroutingname")` thank you very much.